# Get from WatchOS near RealTime HR Data without register data or contribute rings

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

There is a way to get the HR form apple watch without start an HKWorkoutSession with an HKLiveWorkoutBuilder or to restrict the writing in Health Kit of any data form HKLiveWorkoutBuilder and HKWorkoutSession.

I'm interested in any method that can achieve retrieving the "Real Time" HR without modifying HealthKit Data and Rings .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use HKAnchoredObjectQuery to search only for new data added to HealthKit it avoid query all the data, so you can get the latest heart rate values in the following way once you have granted the permissions:

```
    private let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    private let heartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!
    private let heartRateUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")

    /**
     Start to measure the heart rate.
     */
    func startToMeasure() {
        self.healthStore.execute(self.createStreamingQuery())
    }


    /**
    Create a query to receive new heart rate data from the HealthKit store.

    - returns: The created query
    */
    private func createStreamingQuery() -> HKQuery {
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date(), end: nil, options: [])

        let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: heartRateType, predicate: predicate, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) {
            (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
            self.formatSamples(samples: samples)
        }

        query.updateHandler = { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
            self.formatSamples(samples: samples)
        }

        return query
    }
    
    /**
     Format the samples received from HealthKit.

     - parameter samples: Some samples
     */
    private func formatSamples(samples: [HKSample]?) {
        guard let samples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }
        guard let quantity = samples.last?.quantity else { return }

        let value = Int(quantity.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit))
        print("HeartRate: \(value)")
    }
```